# Running a .Rexec on a .Rmd from command prompt

Tags: r, command, r-markdown

So I've followed [this blog](http://www.elliothenry.com/r-markdown-to-website/) to create an executable file called r2jekyll

Unfortunately, I'm on Windows so I've had to create the .Rexec called r2jekyll differently

the code for r2jekyll is here:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(knitr)

# Get the filename given as an argument in the shell.
args = commandArgs(TRUE)
filename = args[1]

# Check that it's a .Rmd file.
if(!grepl(".Rmd", filename)) {
  stop("You must specify a .Rmd file.")
}

# Knit and place in _posts.
dir = paste0("../_posts/", Sys.Date(), "-")
output = paste0(dir, sub('.Rmd', '.md', filename))
knit(filename, output)

# Copy .png files to the images directory.
fromdir = "{{ site.url }}/images"
todir = "../images"

pics = list.files(fromdir, ".png")
pics = sapply(pics, function(x) paste(fromdir, x, sep="/"))
file.copy(pics, todir)

unlink("{{ site.url }}", recursive = TRUE)
```

That all works fine, I can run my r2jekyll rexec (thanks to [this blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-r-files-executable-under-windows/)) it runs but nothing happens

I'm up to the last step to run the r2jekyll on a file i've called first_test.Rmd

I run the following code in command prompt

```
cd (go to directory where my r2jekyll and my first_test.Rmd are sitting)
```

then

```
r2jekyll.rexec first_test.Rmd (the blog author used this code, he is on a mac)
```

and I get the following error

Error: You must specify a .Rmd file.
Execution halted

So my question is: how do I get my r2jekyll.Rexec to do its thing to the first_test.Rmd

Comment: What do you get when you add `cat(args, ":", filename, "\n")` before the `stop()`?

Comment: In addition: What is the output of `ftype RScriptExecutable`?

Comment: the output of the ftype RScriptExecutable is a .Rexec file which I've called r2jekyll. I'll try adding in the cat(args ...) bit in a few hours.

Comment: I'm confused, why will adding the cat argument before the stop() do anything? The stop there tests if the file is a .Rmd and if not it goes "no bro"

Comment: It is for debugging. For some reason the `stop` terminates the execution.

Comment: ah ok, i still got the error:  : NA
Error: You must specify a .Rmd file.
Execution halted feel free to move this to chat if you think we're having an extended conversation in comments, i don't have enough reputation yet

Comment: Ok. The script was called without arguments. Are you sure you included the trailing `%*` when defining the `ftype`?

Comment: I just deleted the r2jekyll and did the whole thing again to make sure, i still get the error. Is this worth figuring out or should I just try wordpress, i see there's a package for R that allows you to post rmd to wordpress

Comment: If you are not tied to jekyll then go for blogdown!